# WooCommerce: hiding out-of-stock products only on Shop page, not on category archive pages

Tags: woocommerce

Checking "Hide out of stock items from the catalog" option hides out-of-stock products everywhere. I want to hide them from the Shop page, but not from individual category archive pages (http://.../product-category/category1/, http://.../product-category/category2/, etc).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by creating a file called `content-product.php` in `yourtheme/woocommerce` and copying the contents of the file `content-product.php` in `woocommerce/templates`. What you need to change is on line 25.

```
if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_visible())
```

and add `|| !$product->is_in_stock()` to the if statement. The if statement should look like:

```
if ( ! $product || ! $product->is_visible() || !$product->is_in_stock() )
```

Adding `|| !$product->is_in_stock()` will check to see if the product is in stock, if not it won't show it in the loop.

Comment: This works but the pagination is broken - the main loop still counts the out of stock products - i.e. if there was 8 products shown on the first page and 3 are out of stock only 5 are left even though there is more on the next page.