# Wordpress Woocommerce Show all in stock and out of stock items in their respective categories

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, categories, stock

Can someone help me with some PHP to add to Functions that will show all inventory in stock out and of stock when viewing the category that the product belongs to? By default my site hides out of stock items on the shop page and i just want to be able to see all items when viewing by category.

I searched and searched but couldnt find anyone wanting to do the same thing.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/28331515/4961700

Comment: Solar Mike i tried these instructions and it didnt work. I already have woocom in my child theme as well so all i did was modify line 25 but changed it back to what its already at.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the one person who tried to help I was able to gets this issue resolved using conditional tag is_product_category()